# How to manage different kinds of models with spatie/laravel-medialibrary?

Tags: laravel

I want to use the library "[spatie/laravel-medialibrary](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v10/introduction)" to manage the medias of my models.

The problem I have is that I have models with integer keys, some models with string keys, and some models with uuid keys.

But the table "media" is only for integer models (see the column "model_id").

Is it possible to have different media tables regarding the types of the keys ?

Comment: Can I ask for the reason for this approach? If you want to avoid exposing auto-increment IDs on FE, I would suggest adding another UUID column to model and keep that integer auto-increment key for internal uses!